# Scaffold-DbContext automatically adds plural "s" / EntityFrameworkCore 6.0.4

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I have an existing database and want to use entityframework with the db first approach. I found a lot of people asking how to pluralize their DbSet-property-names in their DbContext class but I do exactly have the opposite problem. When I run Scaffold-DbContext from the package-manager console in vs it creates the database model and automatically adds an "s" to all my DbSet-names (which I dont want).

Does anyone have an idea why this happens or how do I prevent Scaffold-DbContext from doing this?

The full command I'm using is

```
Scaffold-DbContext -UseDatabaseNames "{constring}" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir "Entities" -ContextDir ".\" -Context "MyContext"
```

Comment: did you try this https://romiller.com/2017/02/10/ef-core-1-1-pluralization-in-reverse-engineer/

Comment: are you on ef core 5?

Comment: *and automatically adds an "s" to all my DbSet-names (which I dont want)* - properties that represent collections *should* be plural; it makes the code read more logically and gives you hints about the kinds of operations you can perform. `object.Name.All(..)` *looks wrong* - at a glance Name would seem like it's a string, so an operation that operates on an enumerable, would be operating on the chars of the string, so `object.Name.All` looks like it should evaluate something for every char in a string, rather than "every string in a collection of strings"

Comment: `object.Names.All(...)` reads correctly and automatically implies that enumeration ops like Select, Where etc will be working against a collection of names. "But Intellisense can tell me.." is not a counter to this because it's not visible all the time, and hovering *everything* to check whether it's a collection or a singular is incredibly tedious

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using EF Core 5, then you can use the below

> To disable the pluralizer, use -NoPluralize switch on Scaffold-DbContext.

This is as per documentation given by [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/breaking-changes#pluralizer)